# How to fix parentheses in string programmatically in VB .net?

Tags: vb.net

I have a string like string bottom which contain parentheses, but wrong direction:

```
)LAST OUTPOST(
)My name is max(   Just driving sideways, no big deal
I don’t think you ever back down.
```

And I want fix that like this:

```
(LAST OUTPOST)
(My name is Clint max)   Just driving sideways, no big deal
I don’t think you ever back down.
```

How can I do that?
Thank you all for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using a simple string replacement using [`string.Replace(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace):

```
Dim myString As String

myString = ")LAST OUTPOST(
)My name is max(   Just driving sideways, no big deal
I don’t think you ever back down."

myString = myString.Replace("(", "((").Replace(")", "(").Replace("((", ")")
Console.WriteLine(myString)
```

Output:

```
(LAST OUTPOST)
(My name is max)   Just driving sideways, no big deal
I don't think you ever back down.
```

#### How does it work?

The string needs a three-step replacement:

1. Replace all right parenthesis with double right parenthesis - `.Replace("(", "((")`
2. Replace all left parenthesis with right parenthesis - `.Replace(")", "(")`
3. Replace all double right parenthesis with single left parenthesis - `Replace("((", ")")`

Three steps are required because you can't swap one to the other without ending up with them all the same.

Comment: Good idea, although I'd probably use some other character which I'm sure does not appear in the text as the "temporary replacement character".

Comment: @Heinzi That's a good suggestion as it may be that other text has a double parenthesis and therefore this would fail

Comment: @Martin WOW I had not thought about it at all that works nice 
thank you dear martin .

Comment: @vahidAraghi You're most welcome, glad to help.